# Using injection instead of composition or inheritance to share common service logic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, service

I have an Angular application that interacts with several REST APIs. There is some common logic when sending requests to these APIs (for example, logging the API name and endpoint). I want to have a seperate service for each API (`ApiAService`, `ApiBService`, etc), but I don't want to repeat the common logic.

I'd like to do this by creating a core service that each service depends on, but I'm not sure how to do it because the core service would need some configuration that would be specific to each place it's used (for example, the API name).

I know how to do this using traditional composition or inheritance:

#### Composition

I could make a non-injectable service class that accepts some configuration and instantiate it for each individual API service:

```
class RequestService(apiName: string) {
  public makeRequest(url: string, ...) {...}
}

@Injectable()
class ApiAService {
  private readonly requestService = new RequestService("API A")

  public queryEndpoint() {
    return this.requestService.makeRequest(...)
  }
}
```

#### Inheritance

I could make the base request service abstract and extend it for each individual API:

```
@Injectable()
abstract class ApiService {
  abstract apiName: string;

  protected makeRequest(url: string, ...) {...}
}

@Injectable()
class ApiAService extends ApiService {
  private readonly apiName = "API A"

  public queryEndpoint() {
    return this.makeRequest(...)
  }
}
```

---

However, I *think* the most idiomatic Angular way is through dependency injection, and it has the advantage of being able to be swapped out for testing. But if I just add `apiName` to the injectable core service's constructor, I have no way to actually set the property when depending on it. I don't care if each service has its own instance of `RequestService` - it doesn't need to be a singleton.

How can I do this?

```
@Injectable()
class RequestService {
  constructor(private apiName: string) {}

  public makeRequest(url: string, ...) {...}
}

@Injectable()
class ApiAService {
  constructor(private requestService: RequestService) {} // How do I inject apiName here?

  public queryEndpoint() {
    return this.requestService.makeRequest(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an *interceptor* for the things that are common to all requests? https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it but in my case I'm using the `fetch` API rather than Angular's built-in service. Also I'd still be interested in a way to accomplish this task in a general sense (outside of just requests) as it would be useful in other scenarios too

Comment: I'm not an angular person, but from a general typescript perspective it seems like you could just instantiate the service in the constructor.  But I guess that's the same as the composition version that you don't want. `class ApiAService { private requestService: RequestService; constructor() { this.requestService = new RequestService("Api A"); } }`